# Abstract matrix to a high power

Tags: matrices

What would be the best way of finding the matrix below to the $n$th power?

$$\pmatrix {1-x&x\\y&1-y}^n$$

The only condition I have is that $0 \lt x+y \lt 2$. I would've usually thought to diagonalise this with eigenvalues and eigenvectors however I don't think this is possible? Could anyone suggest any other ways?

Comment: Why do you think that diagonalization won't work?

Comment: Why not try to diagonalize it? You will always have $1$ as an eigenvalue, since your rows all sum to $1$.

Comment: But when I tried I do det(A-rI)=0 it was very complex to solve

Comment: @JamesO'dare Complicated expressions pop up all the time.   Sometimes, you just have to work through it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can write this matrix in the form
$$
A = \pmatrix{1-x & x\\ y & 1-y} = I + \overbrace{\pmatrix{x\\-y}\pmatrix{-1 & 1}}^B = I + B,
$$
where $I$ dentoes the identity matrix. Because $B$ is a rank-1 matrix, its eigenvalues are easy to find: one eigenvalue is $0$, the other is $-(x + y)$. Thus, the eigenvalues of $A$ are $1-0 = 1$ and $1 -(x+y) = 1 - x - y$.

We conclude that $A$ will be diagonalizable with eigenvalues $1$ and $1 - (x+y)$. Verify that an eigenvector associated with $1$ will be $(1,1)$. An eigenvector associated with $1 -x-y$ is the vector $(x,-y)$. Thus, we have
$$
A = \pmatrix{1 & x\\1 & -y}^{-1} \pmatrix{1&0\\0&1 - x - y} \pmatrix{1&x\\1&-y}\\
= \left[\frac{1}{x + y}\pmatrix{y & x\\1 & -1}\right] \pmatrix{1&0\\0&1 - x - y} \pmatrix{1&x\\1&-y}.
$$
You should be able to take it from there.

Comment: Thank you I see from here!

Comment: its $I + B$ why the minus sign

Comment: You have a “random” change of sign. The eigenvalue is $1-x-y$ and not $1+x+y$ unless the characteristic is $2$ in which case it doesn’t matter

Answer (score 1):

If you diagonalise $M=SJS^{-1}$, you get

$$J=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0\\0 & 1-x-y\end{bmatrix}$$

$$S=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & {-x\over y}\\1 & 1\end{bmatrix}$$

$$S^{-1}=\begin{bmatrix} {y\over x+y} & {x\over x+y}\\{-y\over x+y} & {y\over x+y}\end{bmatrix}$$

And $M^n=SJ^nS^{-1}$

Answer (score 0):

$$\begin{align}|A-\lambda I|&=\left|\begin{matrix}1-x-\lambda&x\\y&1-y-\lambda\end{matrix}\right|\\&=(1-x-\lambda)(1-y-\lambda)-xy\\&=1-y-\lambda-x+xy+\lambda x-\lambda+\lambda y+\lambda^2-xy\\&=1-x-y+\lambda x+\lambda y-2\lambda+\lambda^2\\&=(\lambda-1)(\lambda +x+y-1)\end{align}$$

Equating this to $0$, you get the two eigenvalues $1$ and $1-x-y$ which are the diagonal entries of the diagonal matrix you require.

You can now use the equation $A\bf v=\lambda\bf v$ with the eigenvalues to find the eigenvectors and proceed.